# Per-session persistent sockets in a web application

Tags: perl, sockets

I have a perl web application ([CGI::Application](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI%3a%3aApplication) with [ModPerl::Registry](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/ModPerl%3a%3aRegistry)) which connects to a authenticated custom server over a socket and exchanges data (command/response) with it. Currently the web application connects to the server, authenticates and disconnects on every page request - even for the same user.

Is there some way I can use the same socket over multiple page requests which share a common session id? Creating a separate daemon that proxies connections and makes them persistent is an option I am exploring, but would like to know if there are any simpler solutions.

I have no control over the design of the custom server unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not a Perl/CGI master, but doesn't `mod_perl` allow you creating persistent objects that live across HTTP requests?

Comment: Not sure if that can be done with ModPerl::Registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the [same question](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=880524) was asked on PerlMonks.  The responses there point in the right direction, but the issue seems to be that you want one cached connection per session, not one cached connection per session per httpd thread/process.  You might have to resort to a separate proxy process to get the behaviour you want.

Comment: Yes - waited for a few days for a response before posting again. I'll accept this.